# Do I have copyright for uncharged work when being on contract

Tags: software-industry, software-development, contractors, intellectual-property, ownership

I am a contractor working for a client in EU. In order to cover the requirements of the application we are building I wrote a small implementation of a framework. At least for half of the work on this framework I have not charged. The code itself produced by the company I am contracted at comes with MIT copyright.

Am I allowed to publish my work under my name if I have not charged for at least 50% of it?

It should be noted the framework is a bootstrap implementation of an CQRS/Event Sourcing type of setup/pattern.

Comment: VTC as op needs to speak with a lawyer not the internet.

Comment: Is your contract software development per hour, or do you sell a finished product that you built in your own time?

Comment: Per hour, no finished work.

Comment: VTC This is a contract issue, not a general interest question.

Comment: Next time, use a contract like this one: https://github.com/samuelsycamore/contract-killer (there are several translations/adaptations of that contract floating around). Also your question doesn't make much sense. "if I have not charged for at least 50% of it?" Why is that? Does your client know this? Did you charge for 100% of it? But is it your client who's refusing to pay the full amount? In any case, if you didn't charge for something, that just makes you bad at business. And not charging for something doesn't give you additional rights to it, so that part of your question is irrelevant.

Comment: Also, your question can only be answered based on the contract you used. What does your contract say?

Answer (score 4):

The licence and the copyright are completely separate things.

Who owns the copyright in the work you have created depends on your contract with the client, and the copyright law in the country where you are working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make this clear in your contract. The client will expect that they can take your code and do whatever they like with it after they paid your bill, without asking you for permission. So at the very least they will want a license to use all your code.

Comment: It is already MIT license so that is not a problem. It is more about placing my name as a copywright on each copy Of my work.

Comment: Make sure you have clear defendable position on "my work"